# Computing the nearest neighbours of a choosen site in both, a square and triangular lattice

Tags: c, algorithm, simulation, montecarlo

I'm new in programming, and I've been trying to make functions (in C) that compute the nearest neighbours of a site *i* in a square lattice of NxN sites and, in a triangular lattice.

So far, for the square lattice [Square lattice example. We have 4 nearest neighbours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQS1s.png) is easy, the first four nerest neighbours of a site *i* can be written as:

- *i+1*, for the right neighbour,
- *i-1*, for the left neighbour, and so on for the upper and bottom neighbours.

The problem is when I consider a triangular lattice [triangular lattice example. We have 6 nearest neighbours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N4pq.png). I can't find a similar formula using the label *i*, for the other sites neigbours than the left and right respectively. Should I include some angles in my formulation?

Note: The site *i* is chosen at random, next, I have to find its nearest neighbours in each case.

EDIT: The following, is the code corresponding to the neighbours of a square lattice. There, I'm not considering still periodic boundary conditions. This program gives us the nearest four neighbours of a site (introduced by the user)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define L 5 // The lattice is LxL

int site;

int calculate_neighbours(int i){ //we define a function that calculate the desired neighbours of a site introduced by the user

    /*We define functions for each neigbours*/

    //Right neighbour
    int nr;
    nr=i+1;

/*If the selected site is is the right border of the lattice*/
    for(int k=0;k<L+1;k++){
        if(site==k*L){
            nr=L*(k-1)+1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n right= %d",nr);

//////////////////////////////////////////

//Left neighbour
    int nl;
    nl=i-1;

/*If the selected site is is the left border of the lattice*/
    for(int k=1;k<L+1;k++){
        if(site==(k-1)*L+1){
            nl=L*k;
        }
    }
    printf("\n left= %d",nl);
    //////////////////////////////////

    //Upper neigbour

     int nu;
     nu=i-L;

 /*If the selected site is in the upper border of the lattice*/
     for(int p=L-1;p>-1;p--){
        if(site==L-p){
            nu=L*L-p;
        }
    }
    printf("\n up= %d",nu);

    ////////////////////////////////////////

    //Bottom neighbour

    int nd;
    nd=i+L;

 /*If The chosen site is in the bottom border*/
    for(int p=L-1;p>-1;p--){
        if(site==L*L-p){
            nd=L-p;
        }
    }
    printf("\n down= %d",nd);


/////////////////////////

 /*Main function*/

 int main(void){
    int cont, M[L][L];
     cont=1;

   /*Print the matrix elements in order*/
    while(cont<L){
        printf("The M-matrix is:\n");
         for (int m=0;m<L;m++){
         printf("\n\n");
            for(int n=0;n<L;n++){
                M[m][n]=cont++;
                printf("%5d",M[m][n]);
            }
        }
}

/*Print the nearest neighbours*/
    printf("\n\nTamaño de la red L= %d",L);
    printf("\nNumero de sitios LxL=%d",L*L);
    printf("\n\nintroduzca un sitio= ");
    scanf("%d",&site);

    if(site==0 || site<0){printf("\nDebes introducir un numero        mayor a cero!\n");}
    else  if(site>0 && site<L*L+1){
        calculate_neighbours(site);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nExcediste el tamaño de la red\n");
     }


  }
```

I still don't know how to start applying something similar to a triangular lattice. That is, introducing some angles? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: This is not related to C#, removed the tag.

Comment: Define the input data. (How the lattice data input to the function?)

Comment: The shape doesn't make a difference.  First create all your nodes and assign a number of each.  Each node has a list of neighbors.  Your input would be a list of neighbors like Node 1 : 2,4,6,8  Node 2 : 3 6 7 9   Node 3 : 1, 5, 7.  There is need for a formula,

Comment: Thanks for your answer @fana, could you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: What you have to do depends on the definition of the problem.
For example, if the arguments given to your function are graph data as others have already commented on, there is nothing difficult.
So i asked "How input".

Comment: It's unclear to me what problem you're experiencing. Can you show us how your triangular matrix is laid out?

Comment: Describe your enumeration of triangular lattice cells

Comment: Equivalent triangles are an illusion. One can 'shift' a square lattice 50% of its 'period', both vertically and horizontally, so that, for instance, the top-left vertex of each 'square' becomes the centre point of the square. You cannot do this with a "triangle lattice" because pairs of triangles are, in fact, rhombuses (with an illusory centre line drawn through.) Nodes have 6 equidistant neighbours, but the triangles come in two species...

Comment: Oh, thanks @jdweng. I will edit my post to show you guys my results for a square lattice, I mean, the code that I made (I don't have problems with that since it works properly). But I'm confused about how to write it if I consider now a triangular lattice. Give me a chance, Thanks again

Comment: Thank you @fana, I just edited my question and added the code that I made for a square lattice. The program asks to the user for a site in a lattice (LxL) and then, it computes the four nearest neighbours of the mentioned site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider (X,Y) coordinate of square lattice:

```
//4x4 Square lattice
Y=0 : 0 1 2 3  //0-3 is X value
Y=1 : 0 1 2 3
Y=2 : 0 1 2 3
Y=3 : 0 1 2 3
```

Then, let's consider this 4x4 data as a Triangle lattice.
If you shift the rows with odd Y values to the right by 0.5, the result shape will look like a Triangle lattice.
And, to consider the neighborhood problem, introduce another coordinate here (U,V) as:

```
//4x4 Triangle lattice
V=0 : 0 2 4 6  //U value for Even rows is {0,2,4,6}
V=1 :  1 3 5 7  //U value for Odd rows is {1,3,5,7}
V=2 : 0 2 4 6
V=3 :  1 3 5 7
```

On this (U,V) cooridnate system, enumerating the 6-neighbors is very easy:

```
(U+2,V)    //right
(U-2,V)    //left
(U-1,V-1) //up left
(U+1,V-1) //up right
(U-1,V+1) //down left
(U+1,V+1) //down right
```

All that is left is the coordinate transformation between (X,Y) and (U,V).
This is also easy:

```
//(X,Y) --> (U,V)
inline void XY2UV( int X, int Y, int &U, int &V )
{
    U = X*2 + ( Y%2 );
    V = Y;
}

//(U,V) --> (X,Y)
inline void UV2XY( int U, int V, int &X, int &Y )
{
    X = U / 2;
    Y = V;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I get it. Let me try this

Comment: Okay. I've been struggling with incorporating this info into the code I already have for a square lattice. Could anyone give me some advice regarding this? @fana @ 
jdweng